# problem with Checking if object is exist in Array or not?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here I am trying to add object in array and checking if object is exist in array or not. for that I am using following code..

```
NSInteger ind = [arrActionList indexOfObject:indexPath];
if (ind >= 0 ) {
    [arrActionList removeObjectAtIndex:ind];
}
else {
    [arrActionList addObject:indexPath];
}
```

Here I suppose that I am doing right.. first I am checking for the index. If it is >= 0 I am removing the object else add a new object.

My problem is if there is no index found for object it assigns a garbage value to my integer variable. I suppose it should be -1 but it isn't so my next line in which I am removing object throw error.

ind = 2147483647

Any help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Official Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) might be helpful.

In a nutshell, `indexOfObject:` returns the constant `NSNotFound` if the specified object is not in the array.  The `NSNotFound` constant has a value of 0x7FFFFFFF, which is equal to 2147483647 in decimal.

Your code should behave correctly if you do:

```
NSInteger ind = [arrActionList indexOfObject:indexPath];
if (ind != NSNotFound) {
    [arrActionList removeObjectAtIndex:ind];
}
else {
    [arrActionList addObject:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need the value of ind later on , you could just write;

```
if ( [arrActionList containsObject:indexPath] ) {
     [arrActionList removeObject:indexPath;
}
else {
    [arrActionList addObject:indexPath];
}
```

Alternatively instead of testing ind >=0, use

```
if (ind != NSNotFound) { ...
```

because that's what the value 2147483647 actually is - it's not a 'garbage' value at all, it's telling you something useful.